# Javascript function not accessing a check boxes checked value by document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

Javascript is not my strong point and I'm trying to write a simple function to count how many checkboxes are selected by the user.  These checkboxes are generated from values stored a database and represent a choice of toppings available for a customer ordering pizza.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countBoxes()
{
var aCounter = 0;
var count = 0;
while (count < 10){
    var aString = 'topping' + count;
    var aCheckbox = document.getElementById(aString);
        if (aCheckbox.checked)
        {
            aCounter++;
        }
    count++;
}
alert(aCounter + 'boxes have been ticked');
}
</script>
```

PHP:

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($product))
{ 
echo "<tr><td>".$row['topping_name']."</td><td>".price($row[$aString])."</td><td>      <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"topping".$counter."\" name=\"topping".$counter."\" value=\"".$row['topping_name']."\" onclick=\"countBoxes()\"\" ></td></tr>";         
$counter + 1;
}
echo "</table>";
```

For some reason the 'checked' state of the check box is not being picked up?  Does anyone know why this is?

Generated HTML

```
<table><tr><td>Pepperoni</td><td>0.00</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="topping"       name="topping" value="Pepperoni" onclick="countBoxes()"" ></td></tr><tr><td>Ham</td>       <td>0.00</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="topping" value="Ham" onclick="countBoxes()"" ></td></tr><tr><td>Sausage</td><td>0.00</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="topping" value="Sausage" onclick="countBoxes()"" ></td></tr><tr><td>Red Onions</td><td>0.00</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="topping" value="Red Onions" onclick="countBoxes()"" ></td></tr></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Do I misunderstand your question or does your php code not generate checkboxes?

Comment: The php generates checkboxes which have unique ids topping0, topping1 and so on

Comment: And I should mention the checkboxes call the function by using the onClick event

Comment: @user2802882 Could you show the generated HTML instead?

Comment: Sorry, I was somewhat confused. Why do you give each topping a unique `name`? Wouldn't it be easier to have one `name="toppings"`? You could then use `document.getElementsByName('toppings')` and iterate over them.

Comment: If you are using an outdated browser, you might need to compare use `checked == 'checked'`. Also, please note that your output is insecure, vulnerable to XSS and CSRF attacks, and could potentially cause problems if you have special characters in your topping names.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been solved by  the OP. He simply forgot to initialize his `$counter` variable in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, one really useful tip is to view the generated html, which may seem obvious but it didn't occur to me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace

```
onclick="countBoxes();"
```

by

```
onchange="countBoxes();"
```

and change the javascript function by

```
function countBoxes()
{
  var aCounter = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var element = null;
while (element = document.getElementById('topping' + count)){
    if (element.checked)
      aCounter++;
    count++;
}
alert(aCounter + 'boxes have been ticked');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/oWAcegE/2/

Comment: Thank you for your help, I spotted another error in my php, I had failed to initialise $counter and set it to increment by $counter = $counter + 1

Comment: @user2802882 Why did you select an answer that wasn't your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem it's when you write

```
if (aCheckbox.checked)
```

because if your aCheckbox = null, you have an error on aCheckbox.checked

```
if ( aCheckbox && aCheckbox.checked)
```

the jsFiddle can help you

http://jsfiddle.net/NNgFu/